# Quando executo minha função SQL ela retorna NULL, mesmo estando com dados inseridos no banco

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Criei uma função SQL para calcular as calorias diárias do usuário multiplicando a sua taxa metabólica basal pelo nível de atividade física. O WorkBench não apresenta nenhum erro ao implementar a minha função, mas quando a executo ela retorna `NULL`.

Os dados inseridos no banco são:

Tabela `proc_dieta`:

| met_basal |
| --- |
| 1872 |

Tabela `usuario`:

| sexo | atv_fisica |
| --- | --- |
| Masculino | Baixa |

Segue, em baixo, a função criada:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `funcao_jovem`(id INT) 
RETURNS decimal(10,2)
BEGIN

    DECLARE fator_atividade DECIMAL(10,2);
    DECLARE calorias_diarias DECIMAL(10,2);
    DECLARE sexo VARCHAR(15);
    DECLARE atv_fisica VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE met_basal INT;

    SELECT met_basal, atv_fisica, sexo INTO met_basal, atv_fisica, sexo 
    FROM usuario, proc_dieta 
    WHERE proc_dieta.cod_cad = usuario.cod_cad  
    AND usuario.cod_cad = id;

    IF (sexo = 'Masculino') THEN 
        IF (atv_fisica = 'Baixa') THEN SET fator_atividade = 1.60;
        ELSEIF (atv_fisica = 'Alta') THEN SET fator_atividade = 6.00;
        ELSE SET fator_atividade = 2.5; END IF;
    ELSE 
        IF (atv_fisica = 'Baixa') THEN SET fator_atividade = 1.50;
        ELSEIF (atv_fisica = 'Alta') THEN SET fator_atividade = 6.00;
        ELSE SET fator_atividade = 2.2; END IF;
    END IF;
    
     SET calorias_diarias = met_basal * fator_atividade; 
    
    RETURN calorias_diarias;
END
```

Comment: Parece que o problema está no SELECT.

Comment: sexo INTO met_basal, isso tá certo?

Comment: Sim, pois os dados no INTO seguem a mesma sequência do que foi apresentado no SELECT " met_basal, atv_fisica, sexo INTO met_basal, atv_fisica, sexo "

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que a consulta apenas deva devolver um resultado, visto que toda a lógica posterior tem em conta variáveis cujo valor é obtido a partir da própria consulta.

A consulta parece-me ter "problemas". Talvez algo deste género funcione:

```
CREATE DEFINER='root'@'localhost' FUNCTION 'funcao_jovem'(id INT) 
RETURNS decimal(10,2)
BEGIN

    DECLARE fator_atividade DECIMAL(10,2)
    DECLARE calorias_diarias DECIMAL(10,2)

    SELECT  met_basal
        ,   atv_fisica
        ,   sexo 
    INTO    @met_basal
        ,   @atv_fisica
        ,   @sexo 
    FROM    usuario
        ,   proc_dieta 
    WHERE   proc_dieta.cod_cad  = usuario.cod_cad  
        AND usuario.cod_cad     = id
    LIMIT 1

    IF (sexo = 'Masculino') THEN 
        IF (atv_fisica = 'Baixa') THEN SET fator_atividade = 1.60
        ELSEIF (atv_fisica = 'Alta') THEN SET fator_atividade = 6.00
        ELSE SET fator_atividade = 2.5; END IF
    ELSE 
        IF (atv_fisica = 'Baixa') THEN SET fator_atividade = 1.50
        ELSEIF (atv_fisica = 'Alta') THEN SET fator_atividade = 6.00
        ELSE SET fator_atividade = 2.2; END IF
    END IF
    
    SET calorias_diarias = @met_basal * fator_atividade
    
    RETURN calorias_diarias
END
```

Comment: ao executar código aparece esse erro " ERROR 1054: Unknown column 'sexo' in 'field list' " e quando declaro a coluna dita como desconhecida, ela continua retornando NULL